# SSO Authentication inside Add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is it currently possible to get an SSO Token from inside of an Outlook add-in?

**What I want:**

I need an SSO Token. I have my own working API were the plugin should use the SSO Token against to make an auth-request to login into my system.

**Resources I have exhausted so far:**

- The official SSO workflow from the docs.
  **Not possible**: Its still in preview mode and not available for the AppSource.
- MSAL.js inside of the plugin with `acquireTokenSilent`
  **Not possible**: This operation is not supported inside of Iframes, like in Outlook for the web.
- MSAL.js inside of the plugin with redirect workflow
  **Not possible**: In the native Windows version, the redirect opens a new browser window. The redirect process breaks out of the add-in frame into a new browser window.
- MSAL.js inside of the plugin with popup workflow
  **Not possible**: The popup workflow has known issues with IE and Edge